# Scrapy Crawl an spider on scheduled time

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl an spider multiple times on the scheduled time. The next crawl time will be determined after the first crawl finished. Here is my code to do that but the code will be blocked at the first `crawler.start()` line:

```
spidersQ = collections.OrderedDict()

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    global spidersQ
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.amazon.com",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.body)
        lxml_result = root.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'a-section')]/div[contains(@class,'olpOffer')])[1]")

        price = lxml_result[0].text.strip()
        # Now schedule this spider to run again after 5 seconds
        spidersQ[datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)] = QuotesSpider


def main():
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

    process.crawl(QuotesSpider)
    process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)  # the script will block here forever

    while True:
        if datetime.datetime.now() > first(spidersQ):
            schedTime, spider = spidersQ.popitem(last=False)
            process.crawl(spider)
            process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Was able to reproduce. On Ctrl+C it will continue after the `process.start(...)` line. There already was a [bug regarding `CrawlerProcess` and `Ctrl+C`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1279). Maybe it's related somehow and you can debug with the relevant scrapy code sections for this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try with an external module schedule:

[Python job scheduling for humans](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)